# how to benchmark an infinite loop java nio watchservice program

Tags: java, benchmarking

I have a infinite polling loop using java.nio.file.WatchService looking for new files .Inside the loop i have fixed thread pool executor service to process files concurrently.

As the polling service keeps running, how can i benchmark the time taken for a batch of say 10/n files to process.i am able to time each file in the runnable class but how can get the batch processing time ?

Comment: You need to pass an aditional "state-holding" object to all parts of the batch, and then compute your benchmarks when they all finish. Without this additional object, you cannot know if they have all finished or not, specially if something new arrives.

Comment: They say that modern super-computers complete infinite loop under three seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
// inside the listener for the WatchService
final MyTimer t = new MyTimer(); // takes current time, initialized to 0 tasks
for (Change c : allChanges) {
   t.incrementTaskCount(); // synchronized
   launchConcurrentProcess(c, t);
}

// inside your processor, after processing a change
t.decrementTaskCount(); // also synchronized

// inside MyTimer
public void synchronized decrementTaskCount() {       
   totalTasks --;

   // depending on your benchmarking needs, you can do different things here
   // I am printing max time only (= end of last), but min/max/avg may also be nice
   if (totalTasks == 0) {
      System.err.println("The time spent on this batch was " 
          + System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime);
   }
}
```